# Jest simulate doesn't work with react-native input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I have the following test code for react-native.

```
it('changes text', () => {
    wrapper.find(InputBox).at(0).simulate('onChange', { target: { value: 'givenName' } });
    expect(wrapper.find(InputBox).at(0).prop.value).toEqual('given');
  });
```

This gives the following error.

```
 Expected: "given"
 Received: undefined
```

Why is the received name is undefined here??

Answer (score 0):

add s to prop to become props

```
it('changes text', () => {
    wrapper.find(InputBox).at(0).simulate('onChange', { target: { value: 'givenName' } });
    expect(wrapper.find(InputBox).at(0).props.value).toEqual('given');
  });
```